# How to enable Server host name verification in Kafka 2?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is my server.properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSl://localhost:9093

ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.keystore.location=/home/xrobot/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/certificate/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=ffffdd
ssl.key.password=ffffdd
ssl.truststore.location=/home/xrobot/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/certificate/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=ffffdd

ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

If I try to set ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS, then I get this error:

```
[2019-02-26 19:04:00,011] ERROR [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

So how can I enable Server host name verification in Kafka 2 ?

Comment: You have a problem with port 9092. however, your SSL connection is in 9093. Did you try to connect the broker on port 9092?

Comment: @Amin yes, same problem :( What other can I try?

Comment: @xRobot Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

You have set `security.inter.broker.protocol` to SSL. when brokers try to connect each other or Zookeeper they act as a client so, your brokers need to have truststore that contains public key of the CA you used to sign the broker certificates or the public keys of all broker certificates. for complete steps take a look at [Encryption and Authentication using SSL](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl)

I am completely sure that you know each client has to have its own public and private key in a two way SSL authentication.

Comment: I have one single kafka server ( so only 1 certificate ). I already followed all those steps and I got these files: ca-cert,  ca-cert.srl,  ca-key,  cert-file,  cert.pem,  cert-signed,  client.truststore.jks,  key.pem,  server.keystore.jks,  server.truststore.jks.